# How can I post an Images on my Laravel App?

Tags: php, laravel

## Basic Informations

I'm developing a simple web app using Laravel.
and I want to add an image upload and stirage function.

## My issue

I want to save the binary data of the image to the DataBase.
But there is an error message.

```
file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty
```

How can I solve this issue?

## My Codes

### 2020_06_12_085454_create_attachments_table.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateAttachmentsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('attachments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('path');
            $table->text('image');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('attachments');
    }
}
```

### index2.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.front2')
@section('title','mainpage')

@section('content')

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/main2.css') }}">

<div class="profile">
    <div class="name">
        @guest
        <a class="nav-link2" href="{{ route('register')}}">{{ __('Create Accout!')}}</a>
        @else
        <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link2" href="#" role="button">
            {{ Auth::user()->name }}<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
            @csrf
        </form>
        @endguest
    </div>

<div class="aboutme">
  <tbody>
    @foreach($posts as $profile)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ \Str::limit($profile->title, 100) }}</td>
            <td>{{ \Str::limit($profile->body, 250) }}</td>
        </tr>
        <a href="{{ action('ProfileController@delete', ['id' => $profile->id]) }}">delete</a>
        <a href="{{ action('ProfileController@update', ['id' => $profile->id]) }}" class="update">update</a>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
<br>
</div>
</div>

<div class="new">
    <div class="newtitle">
        <h1>New</h1>
    </div>
    
    <div class="container1">
        @foreach ($images as $image)

        <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ $image->image }}" class="images" style="height: 250px; width: 250px; border-radius: 50%;">

       　<a href="{{ action('StoriesController@delete', ['id' => $image->id]) }}">delete</a>
        @endforeach
    <div class="more">
        more...
    </div>
    </div>
</div>


{{ csrf_field() }}
@endsection
```

### StoriesController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Story;
use App\Profile;
use Auth;
use App\Posts;
use App\History;
use App\Attachment;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Storage;

class StoriesController extends Controller
{

  public function __construct()
    {
      $this->middleware('auth');
    }

  public function index(Request $request)
      {
          $images = Attachment::all();
          $cond_title = $request->cond_title;
        if ($cond_title != '') {
            $posts = Profile::where('title', $cond_title)->get();
        } else {
            $posts = Profile::all();
        }
          return view('stories.index2', compact('images','posts','cond_title'));
      }

  public function add()
    {
      return view('stories.create2');
    }

  public function store(Request $request)
  {
        $image = new Attachment();
        $image->image = base64_encode(file_get_contents($request->image));
        $image->save();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the path where the temporary image is stored. To do that do
`$request->file('image')`
so your code becomes

```php
public function store(Request $request)
  {
        $image = new Attachment();
        $image->image = base64_encode(file_get_contents($request->file('image')));
        $image->save();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I modified to `$request->file('image')->pat‌​h()` but the error message `Call to a member function pat‌​h() on null` has appeared.

Comment: @TakamasaYoshizawa use $request->file('image') instead